# Regarding the np.gradient routine

Tags: python, numpy, gradient

I am trying to understand np.gradient() routine for 2D arrays. In the example provided in the documentation, we have:

```
dx = 2.
y = [1., 1.5, 3.5]
np.gradient(np.array([[1, 2, 6], [3, 4, 5]], dtype=float), dx, y)
```

which gives

```
[array([[ 1. ,  1. , -0.5],
        [ 1. ,  1. , -0.5]]),
 array([[2. , 2. , 2. ],
        [2. , 1.7, 0.5]])]
```

I understand how one arrives at the other elements, but why is the 2x2 element in the second array 1.7?
From my understanding, the 2x2 element of the second array should be calculated as:

```
(5-3)/(3.5-1) = 2/2.5 = 0.8
```

What am I doing wrong here?